# UITableView numberOfRowsInSection returns 0 when trying to delete row from one section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with two sections and I am trying to delete a row from one section and insert into the next. Below is how I am doing that,

```
[[PickDataController sharedDataController].picks removeObject:pick];
NSIndexPath *removeIndexPath = indexPath;

[[PickDataController sharedDataController].completePicks insertObject:pick atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *insertIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %ld", (long)[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]);
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[removeIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[insertIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The insertion and deletion happens most of the times , but at times the app crashes with message,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'
```

This is my numberofRowsinSection method,

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0) {
        return [PickDataController sharedDataController].picks.count;
    } else {
        return [PickDataController sharedDataController].completePicks.count;
    }

}
```

When this happens , "numberOfRowsInSection: 0" - is printed in console

Comment: Try creating a local variable for the pick you're deleting (`pickToMove` or something like that). Then remove it from one section and insert `pickToMove` in the other. If you're using core data, why not create an attribute on your `pick` object and let the `fetchedResultsController` do the work for you when the attribute is changed that determines what section your object is displayed in.

Comment: `NSIndexPath *removeIndexPath = indexPath` ... where is `indexPath` created? Seems you set it up above somewhere, remove an object from `.picks`, and *then* set `removeIndexPath`. Whatever `indexPath` was before removing the `pick` might no longer be valid. The return value from `numberOfRowsInSection` will already be zero while attempting to move the last item, and deleting `removeIndexPath` might be off by 1.

Comment: `indexPath` is the indexPath of the selected row and it is having the correct value.I verified that . And the crash is not happening for the last item in section, it is random

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue?